# Ajax response from php, echoing span inside div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm using Ajax to post data to my php file and then retrieving it's response inside a div.
So what I'm doing is echoing `<span class="messageError">Insuficient points!</span>` in case there was an error and `<span class="messageSuccess">Your request was successfully sent!</span>` in case everything was like expected.
On the client side I have this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'newRequest.php',
    data: myData,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result){
        $('.returnMessage').text(result)
    }
});
```

"returnMessage" is the div the response will be loaded in. Everything works fine except for the output that instead of creating a span inside the div it loads the entire string `<span class="messageError">Insuficient points!</span>`...

How can I make the function to create the span inside the div instead of writing the tag as string? Thank You!

Comment: use .html() instead of .text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code to do that:

```
success: function(result){
    $('.returnMessage').html('<span class="messageError">' + result + '</span>');
}
```

Or if the `<span>` is already generated, just change it to `.html()`

```
success: function(result){
    $('.returnMessage').html(result);
}
```

Comment: But the PHP will return the `<span>` element as well, and it may have a different class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just saw this `Everything works fine except for the output that instead of creating a span inside`.

Comment: Ît was kinda dumb from me not to remember that. But i'm too many hours on these codes and my mind is starting to fail. Thank You man!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `html()` method as `text()` encodes the value:

```
$('.returnMessage').html(result)
```